# How to mock ctypes function in Python that uses ctypes.byref for one of the parameters

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am working on a Python wrapper to a DLL/SO. I have verified the code works calling the actual DLL and SO. I would like to unit test my wrapper without requiring the underlying DLL/SO be installed though. I am looking at using [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

The problem I am having trouble with is with functions that take byref parameters and return values that way. For example, if the C fundtion looks something like this:

```
int initialize(char *resource, ulong *new_handle)
{
    // Some code here
    *new_handle = temp_handle;
    return error;
}
```

and the Python code would look like:

```
error_code = library.initialize(resource.encode('ascii'), ctypes.byref(session_handle))
```

I am able to mock the function and set the return value (error_code), but I have not been able to figure out how to set the value that is returned in session_handle.

Is this possible  and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the object passed to `byref` through the `_obj` attribute of the return value:

```
x is ctypes.byref(x)._obj
```

Or at least, you can for now. This is an undocumented API and subject to change.

Once you have the object, you can set its value the usual ctypes way, through its `value` attribute:

```
byref_session_handle._obj.value = whatever
```